# How to Append SQL String in a Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to update the Where Clause of stored procedure based on `if else`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spLocal_GetDetails
@Var1 varchar(255),
@Var2 varchar(255)
As
declare @WhereClause varchar(255)
IF @Var1 = '' and @Var2 = ''
SET @WhereClause='Where T1.Key1='+@Var1 
ELSE
SET @WhereClause= 'T1.Key1='+@Var1 + ' and someValue'+ @Var2+' 

Select *
from [dbo].[Table1] T1 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table2] T2 with(nolock) on T1.KEY=T2.KEY
+ @WhereClause
```

Now I am getting the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spLocal_GetDetails, 
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Where T1.Key1=5' to data type int.

Comment: Read this thoroughly. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: I've added my answer below. But anyway, the code isn't good at all and should be really improved.

Answer (score 2):

I tend not to like generating dynamic SQL ([here's why](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)), in a reasonably simple case such as this I'd opt for something like the following...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spLocal_GetDetails
     @Var1 varchar(255),
     @Var2 varchar(255)
As
    declare @BothKeysEmpty bit

    IF @Var1 = '' and @Var2 = ''
        SET @BothKeysEmpty = 1
    ELSE
        SET @BothKeysEmpty = 0

    select *
      from [dbo].[Table1] T1 
      left join [dbo].[Table2] T2 with(nolock) on T1.KEY=T2.KEY
     where T1.Key1= @Var1
       and (@BothKeysEmpty = 1 OR somevalue = @Var2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues in your code.

First of all:

```
SET @WhereClause='Where T1.Key1='+@MyId
```

`@Id`seems to be an Integer. This means it should be converted!

```
SET @WhereClause='Where T1.Key1='+CONVERT(nvarchar(100),@MyId)
```

Second:

Where do you get `@MyId` from? I don't see it in your code.

And third:

```
SET @WhereClause= 'T1.Key1='+@MyId+ ' and someValue'+ @Var1+' and otherValue='+ @Var2
```

You try to put a string in the where clause. You forget the `=` and you need to mark them as strings using `''`. See here:

```
SET @WhereClause= 'T1.Key1='+CONVERT(nvarchar(100),@MyId)+ ' and someValue='''+ @Var1+''' and otherValue='''+ @Var2 + ''''
```

Comment: this solution is not complete. The OP tries to concatenate a where clause to a non-dynamic query, which will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is run in sqlserver

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spLocal_GetDetails
@Var1 varchar(255),
@Var2 varchar(255)
As
begin
declare @WhereClause varchar(255)
declare @query varchar(max)
IF @Var1 = '' and @Var2 = ''
SET @WhereClause='Where T1.Key1='+convert(varchar(50),@MyId)
ELSE
SET @WhereClause= 'where T1.Key1='+convert(varchar(50),@MyId)+ ' and someValue'+ @Var1+' and otherValue='+ @Var2

SET @query='Select *
from [dbo].[Table1] T1 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table2] T2 with(nolock) on T1.KEY=T2.KEY '
+ @WhereClause

excute(@query)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing sql and t-sql, you should build a query dynamically by creating a temp variable which will hold your sql and then execute it via t-sql

```
SET @query='
Select *
from [dbo].[Table1] T1 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table2] T2 with(nolock) on T1.KEY=T2.KEY
'
+ @WhereClause

excute(@query)
```